# Add <p>paragraph</p> into a div, but create a new div if the div has already 2 paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div .content with two divs inside (.content-1, .content-2).

In the divs that are inside .content, I just want to have a maximum of two paragraphs.

So, when I click in the button "add" I want to add a paragrah inside a div that has only one or zero paragraph, if have 2 I want to create a new div .content-3 and add this paragraph in this third div, and when this third div has two paragraphs I want to create a new div .content-4, and so on..

Im trying to do this, and I already have working the part that I add a paragraph just when a div have 1 or zero paragraph. But now the part that creates a new div if the others already have two, is not working properly.

Do you see why its wrong?

I have here my example working: http://jsfiddle.net/e2f38kgL/1/

html:

```
  <div class="message">
        <input type="text" id="input" onclick="clear();" value="text:"><br>
        <button id="import" class="btn">add</button>
    </div>
<div class="content">
   <div class="content-1">
       <p>text 1</p>
        <p>text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="content-2">
       <p>text 1</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
    var input = $("#input").val();
    var maxdivSize = 2;
    var divContentSize = $(".content > *").length;
    $(".content >*").each(function(){
        var i = 0;
        var numberOfElements = $(this).find("p").length;
        if (numberOfElements < 2){
            $(this).append("<p> "+ input + "</p>");
        }
        else{
            $(".content").append("<div class='content-"+i+1+"'>"+input+"</div>");
        }
        i++;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code,

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    var divContentSize = $(".content > *").length;
    var relDiv = $(".content > div").filter(function () {
        return $(this).children().length !== 2;
    });
    if (relDiv.length) {
        relDiv.append("<p> " + input + "</p>");
    } else {
        $(".content").append("<div class='content-" + (divContentSize + 1) + "'><p>" + input + "</p></div>");
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#input', function () {
    $('#input').val('');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e2f38kgL/2/)